# How to tell which physical disks have bootable MBR?

Tags: windows-7, boot, mbr, bootable-media

The computer I am using right now has 6 physical disks attached. Using the BIOS's "select boot device" functionality I have discovered that I can boot off 3 of these disks *into the exact same bootloader*. This means that all of these disks have the bootable flag set on their MBR, even though I had been under the impression that only 2 of them are in fact bootable.

My question is: is there an easy way to check which disks have a bootable MBR with a command line tool or some OS utility? I am aware of the `DISKPART` tool and its basic functionality, but I haven't found how to view the information I need.

The OS is Windows 7 x64 Ultimate with SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Start Menu and write "compmgmt.msc". This should find one hit ("Computer Managment"; or similar, not using the English Version).

In there, you'll find one sub section dedicated to storage devices/disks.

There you'll find a list of all existing and active partitions together with their flags listed under "Status":

[image: Screenshot]

---

To determine whether a disk has a MBR or a GPT open `diskpart` and run `list disk`.

To show more Information, select a disk using `select disk 0` (or any other number shown in the list), then type `detail disk`.

In a similar way partition Information can be shown once a disk has been selected using `list partition` and `select partition 0` and `detail partition`.

Comment: MBR bootability is an attribute of the *disk*, not of a partition. Therefore I highly doubt a list of partitions can provide this information. Plus, you haven't really given an answer.

Comment: My bad, thought you're talking about having a partition set as "active" - adding some lines for `diskpart`...

Comment: As far as I can tell `detail disk` doesn't do that either. It just tells you if that disk is the one you booted from.

Comment: Reread a bit on the topic. There's no additional flag as far as I'm aware (at least nothing standardized), and it should be up to the partition table (see first part of my answer). But I'm actually curious, whether there's something I missed.

Comment: I 've been reading Wikipedia on MBR, and it now [looks like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PTE) you are correct and I was under the wrong impression. But I 'd certainly like to get a  more authoritative answer.

Comment: @Mario: it seems there *is* an MBR-flag (55h AAh at the end); see [here in German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record#MBR-Signatur) (sorry, English Wikipedia is less clear on this point)

Comment: No, that's just a "magic signature" to properly terminate the MBR. This way programs (Editors, BIOS, bootloader) can be sure that the MBR is complete (to avoid reading into parition data for whatever reason). The entry just states it would be seen as "unbootable" due to the MBR essentially being broken.

Answer (score 3):

In the MBR style, the so-called 'bootable flag' resides in the first byte of the partition entry. If the first bit is set, the partition is marked bootable. For compatibility reasons, the other seven bits are usually left at zero, yielding `0x00` for non-bootable partitions and `0x80` for bootable ones.

[image: Example MBR]

Above is an example of part of a master boot record. Notice the signature `55 AA` at the end. Highlighted in blue is the partition table. Each of the four entries is sixteen bytes long. All but the first are non-bootable (and empty).

Although Windows does not, to my knowledge, have a built-in tool for displaying raw disk data, it is possible to extract this information through DiskPart. Windows's non-standard naming obscures it somewhat, but both here and in the graphical disk manager, the flag is called 'Active'.

[image: DiskPart]

Shown above are details of an apparently bootable partition. The flag can also be set with a subsequent `active` or `inactive` command, or through the graphical disk manager by right-clicking the partitions, then choosing 'Mark partition as (in)active...'.

Answer (score 1):

**Long** drill-down method to find MBR information:

When using compmgmt.msc, [Using Graphical Mode] after right-clicking the target drive, select Properties, then select Hardware tab, Click on the target drive in question, Click Properties, Click Volumes, Click Populate, then the desired target drive information is displayed, including the Partition Style.

**Short** drill-down method to find MBR information:

When using compmgmt.msc, [Using Graphical Mode] right-click the 'Disk 1' (or the target disk desired) in the furthest left box, select Properties, select Volume.  The information is displayed.